# How would I go about wrapping an express.js app with Phonegap and deploying it as a native android app?

Tags: android, cordova, express, phonegap-build

So I have an express.js app that I have already deployed to Heroku and I want to wrap it with Phonegap and deploy it as a native android app. I looked into [charlotte](https://github.com/danieldkim/charlotte) a little bit but am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Here are some links that might be helpful:

- [heroku app](http://textoverflow.herokuapp.com/)
- [github repo](https://github.com/borderpointer/textoverflow)

**P.S.** My app needs to have a server because I need to make server-side third party API calls.

**P.P.S** My app does not have a database.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your question is broad. Narrow your question.

Comment: heavyhorse's answer below helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable CORS on your server (http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html)

then call your server from the UI using the full URL (with host and port)

finally take your WWW directory and package that using phonegap